# Get module name in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

In magento 1 I can get module name using below code:

```
$this->_getModuleName()
```

How can I get module name in helper magento 2?

Comment: In what context do you execute that code? Controller? Block? Helper?... Please improve your question.

Comment: @Vinai i am trying to get module name in observer and helper file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still do that in M2.

`$this->_getModuleName()` would still work, provided your helper class extends `\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper` (which most of the time it should, anyway).

PS: As for fetching the module name in observers, that's a different story. One which needs more details. Or another question even. Do you want to get the module of *the current observer*? You could implement something similar to what `\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper::_getModuleName()` does.

Comment: this should be accepted solution

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

```
echo $moduleName = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but not working

Comment: From request it's possible inside Controller or Observer class I think, but not Helper

Comment: If you add that model in `helper` you will be able to call it in helper too

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __construct (
     ....
     \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
     ....
) {   
     ....
     $this->_request = $request;
     ....
}
```

To get module name :

```
public function getModuleName()
{
     return $this->_request->getModuleName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ***want to get module name*** at ***block class*** then you can get and that  block class have  `Magento\Framework\View\Context;` class object then using `getModuleName()`,you **will get module name**

Comment: I am trying to get module name in observer and helper of my custom module